# Moran's I on 2D arrays/rasters?

Tags: python, raster, autocorrelation, pysal, moran-index

I would like to apply Moran's I spatial auto-correlation measure to 2D arrays or raster files in Python and I am wondering if there is an available implementation for it.

I know Pysal offers an implementation but I was not able to figure how to apply it to 2D data.

Any other libraries/implementations that would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the raster has r rows and c columns, then you can create a pysal W object with:

```
w = pysal.lat2W(r,c)
```

and use that with the Moran class.

More details available at: https://pysal.org/libpysal/generated/libpysal.weights.lat2W.html#libpysal.weights.lat2W

Answer (score 5):

Eventually, with the help of Serge Rey's answer and this [link](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/tutorials/autocorrelation.html#local-autocorrelation) in the documentation, I ended up using pysal's implementation as follows:

```
import pysal as ps
w = ps.lat2W(input_img.shape[0],input_img.shape[1], rook=False, id_type="int")
np.random.seed(12345)
lm = ps.Moran_Local(input_img,w)
moran_significance = np.reshape(lm.p_sim, input_img.shape)
```

In the last line I reshape the array of pseudo p_values (which indicate the significance of the local indicators of spatial association (LISAs) ) for visualization purposes:

[image]

I just leave it here as an answer in case someone finds it useful in the future.

Comment: Very cool! Can you just clarify the `input_img` data type and how to create it?